# How do I set an emblem with GTK/GIO?

Tags: c, gtk, gio

I'm trying to set an emblem using gio

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GFile *gfile = NULL;
    g_type_init();
    gfile = g_file_new_for_path("./foo.txt");
    if (g_file_set_attribute_string(gfile, 
                                    "metadata::emblems", 
                                    "favorite", 
                                    G_FILE_QUERY_INFO_NONE, 
                                    NULL, NULL) == TRUE) {

        puts("Success");
    } else {
        puts("Fail");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if the file exists, the function returns TRUE, which, according the docs means the metadata was set, but Nautilus (GNOME) doesn't display the `favorite` emblem. There are not many example on the net, so I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like metadata::emblems needs an array of strings even if you are only setting one value.
This seems to work:

```
char *value[] = {"favorite", '\0'};
[...]
g_file_set_attribute(file, "metadata::emblems",
                     G_FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_STRINGV,
                     &value[0],
                     G_FILE_QUERY_INFO_NONE,
                     NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Nautilus to show an emblem, you need to actually provide an extension to Nautilus to do so. Your extension should use the [nautilus-info-provider](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libnautilus-extension/stable/libnautilus-extension-nautilus-info-provider.html) interface, and in the [nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libnautilus-extension/stable/libnautilus-extension-nautilus-info-provider.html#nautilus-info-provider-update-file-info)
 function you can call the [nautilus_file_info_add_emblem()](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libnautilus-extension/stable/libnautilus-extension-nautilus-file-info.html#nautilus-file-info-add-emblem) function to add an emblem.

Comment: I want Nautilus to show the "favorite" emblem, which is a stock one, I don't want to *create* a new emblem. I found out that the value of "metadata::emblems" MUST be an array.

Comment: This won't create a new emblem, it will display an existing named emblem.